# Mule error --2 . Failed to invoke method. Message payload is of type string

Tags: java, mule, mule-el, mule-component

I have a mule flow that invokes a method and sets the return value in the payload .

Here's the part of my flow that does it

```
<flow name="PositiveFlow1" doc:name="PositiveFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9293" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <invoke object-ref="TestUtils1"
        method="getSignedClaimWrapper"
        doc:name="Invoke"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="clientcontext" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <flow-ref name="_subflow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </flow>
```

`getSignedClaimWrapper` returns a `Base64` encoded string .

Here's my stack trace.

```
Message               : Failed to invoke com.test.TestUtils@2cfe109a. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String; (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)
  com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL:64 (null)
2. Failed to invoke com.test.TestUtils@2cfe109a. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor:178 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL.encode(Base64URL.java:64)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL.encode(Base64URL.java:91)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.Header.toBase64URL(Header.java:238)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I'm guessing this is because Mule has a limitation on handling Base64 Strings. As the test cases for the `TestUtils` class seem to work perfectly fine on their own.

Any insight on what might be happening or possible solutions would be appreciated!

Spring bean from mule flow:

```
    <spring:bean id="TestUtils1"   class="com.package.TestUtils"/>    
</spring:beans>
```

Corresponding portion of Java class :

```
public String getSignedClaimWrapper() throws KeyLoadException,
    KeyNotFoundException, SignException, SignerNotInitializedException
    {

        String signedClaim = rsaTokenSigner.signClaim(claimsSet);// returns a base64 encoded string.

        System.out.println("The signed claim is " + signedClaim);
        return signedClaim;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls display the java class and the method you are trying to invoke ?? Also the spring bean in Mule config ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commons codec library included with mule is more older than the one your rsaTokenSigner needs. It doenst contain that method indeed.

I would try to use a [classpath override](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule) and including the newer library with your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But did you mean block instead of override?

Comment: Doesnt help. Overriding doesnt change anything and blocking throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: After you blocked, did you added the library to your app or to lib/user?

Comment: I added it to the pom. Im working on it from eclipse. Where do I add it then?

Comment: What do you mean, plain eclipse or studio?
Are you running it as maven or as normal app?
Personally I would test doing a manual deploy to a container before trying to make it work in eclipse/studio.